# What is the best method to receive, process, and then return XML data using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, http, dom, simplexml

I need to create a PHP script that receives XML input via an HTTP POST request, processes it, and then returns an XML response. I have spent quite a while attempting this on my own, and here is what I have so far.

I first quickly threw together an HTML form that allows a user to submit XML data as a string, an XML URI as a string, or an XML URI to my PHP script. This form is for testing only, as I am only tasked with creating this script.

In my PHP script I do some input handling...

```
// Checks that some XML input has been given
if (!(isset($_POST['xmlinput']))) {
    handleErrors("No XML Input Given");
}

// Creates a new DOM Document
$domdoc = new DomDocument;

// Sets the URL of the XML Schema
$xmlschema = "xmlschema.xsd";

// If XML input is a file, tries to load it
if (file_exists($_POST['xmlinput'])) {
    if (!$domdoc->load($_POST['xmlinput'])) {
        handleErrors("Error in XML File");
    }
}
// If XML input is not a file, tries to load it as a string
else {
    if (!$domdoc->loadXML($_POST['xmlinput'])) {
        handleErrors("Error in XML Document");
    }
}

// Validates the XML against the schema
if (!($domdoc->schemaValidate($xmlschema))) {
    handleErrors("XML Does Not Conform To Schema");
}
```

I then do some stuff based on what the XML data is, and then I want to generate an XML response. I am fairly certain I can create XML in DOM or SimpleXML, but I simply do not understand how to return it to the original page. Also, is this the best method to handle XML input in PHP? I have seen a ton of posts about php://input or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA but these don't seem to be any better than the method I use. Any information you can give me would be a big help. If I can clarify any more, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, you create your xml document using [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php),

then just

`echo $xml->asXML();`

If you need to post xml data to a webservice,

You can use the following code to acheive that.

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to use the Error Suppression Operator but add the proper [Option](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) for that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($source, LIBXML_NOERROR);
```

An alternative would be to use [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

A response is basically just what the webserver sends back to the requesting client, so to send an XML response, you simply echo your XML it with an XML header, e.g.

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: I already use libxml_use_interal_errors for error processing but thank you. Thank you for the feedback.